# MvvmCross binding property of custom type to custom view

Tags: mvvm, binding, viewmodel, mvvmcross, custom-view

I tried bind property of custom type in View Model with custom View, but in Binder method "SetValue(object value)" value is always null. Why it happens? Is it impossible bind property of custom type with custom view in MvvmCross?

My ViewModel:

```
public class RecipesFiltersVM : MvxViewModel
{
    public SearchField DishField { get; private set; }
    public SearchField CuisineField { get; private set; }
    public SearchField IngredientField { get; private set; }

    private readonly IFiltersService _filtersService;

    public RecipesFiltersVM(IFiltersService filtersService)
    {
        _filtersService = filtersService;

        UpdateSearchFields ();
    }

    private async void UpdateSearchFields ()
    {
        var allFilters = await _filtersService.LoadAllFilters ();

        DishField = new SearchField (
            allFilters
            .Where(f => f.Type == FilterType.Dish)
            .ToList()
        );
        CuisineField = new SearchField (
            allFilters
            .Where(f => f.Type == FilterType.Cuisine)
            .ToList()
        );
        IngredientField = new SearchField (
            allFilters
            .Where(f => f.Type == FilterType.Ingredient)
            .ToList()
        );
    }
}
```

My SearchField:

```
public class SearchField : MvxViewModel
{
    private String _searchResult;
    public String SearchResult {
        get { return _searchResult; }
        set {
            _searchResult = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => SearchResult);
            UpdateFoundFilters ();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Filter> _foundFilters;
    public ObservableCollection<Filter> FoundFilters {
        get { return _foundFilters; }
        set {
            _foundFilters = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => FoundFilters);
        }
    }
}
```

In CustomView:

```
public class SearchFieldView : UIView
{
    public UITextField SearchResult { get { return _searchResult; } }
    private UITextField _searchResult;

    public UITableView FoundFilters { get { return _foundFilters; } }
    private UITableView _foundFilters;
}
```

In Binder:

```
public class SearchFieldViewWithSearchFieldBinder : MvxTargetBinding
{
    protected SearchFieldView SearchFieldView {
        get { return (SearchFieldView)Target; }
    }

    public SearchFieldViewWithSearchFieldBinder (SearchFieldView target)
        : base (target)
    {

    }

    public override void SetValue (object value)
    {
        //value is always null!
    }

    public override Type TargetType {
        get
        {
            return typeof(SearchField);
        }
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode {
        get
        {
            return MvxBindingMode.TwoWay;
        }
    }
}
```

Setup:

```
protected override void FillTargetFactories (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.Construction.IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<SearchFieldView> (
            "SearchField",
            indicators => new SearchFieldViewWithSearchFieldBinder(indicators)
        );
        base.FillTargetFactories (registry);
    }
```

In ViewController:

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<RecipesFiltersDialog, RecipesFiltersVM>();
set.Bind (_dish).For("SearchField").To (vm => vm.DishField);
set.Bind (_cuisine).For("SearchField").To (vm => vm.CuisineField);
set.Bind (_ingredient).For("SearchField").To (vm => vm.IngredientField);
set.Apply ();
```

**UPD**

Solved with two ways update ViewModel code. First I changed custom property declaration like:

```
private SearchField _dishField;
    public SearchField DishField {
        get
        {
            return _dishField;
        }
        set
        {
            _dishField = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => DishField);
        }
    }
```

Second I initialize my properties in ViewModel constructor before UpdateSearchFields () execution:

```
public RecipesFiltersVM(IFiltersService filtersService)
    {
        _filtersService = filtersService;

        DishField = new SearchField (new List<Filter> ());
        CuisineField = new SearchField (new List<Filter> ());
        IngredientField = new SearchField (new List<Filter> ());

        UpdateSearchFields ();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post even more code? e.g. a full viewmodel showing where DishField is set to a non-null value? Something like the N+1 MvxView video might also help with an alternative approach - https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-32-ViewModels/Compo.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs

Comment: @Stuart I added more code in ViewModel and I saw my trouble. Thanks for answer, it's very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with [Stuart's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176097/mvvmcross-binding-property-of-custom-type-to-custom-view#comment50387566_31176097) comment in two ways update ViewModel code. First I changed custom property declaration like:

```
private SearchField _dishField;
    public SearchField DishField {
        get
        {
            return _dishField;
        }
        set
        {
            _dishField = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged (() => DishField);
        }
    }
```

Second I initialize my properties in ViewModel constructor before UpdateSearchFields () execution:

```
public RecipesFiltersVM(IFiltersService filtersService)
    {
        _filtersService = filtersService;

        DishField = new SearchField (new List<Filter> ());
        CuisineField = new SearchField (new List<Filter> ());
        IngredientField = new SearchField (new List<Filter> ());

        UpdateSearchFields ();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own custom bindings for your custom view.  For instance if you have followed the normal MvvmCross practice of using public C# properties and C# events to define the items in your custom view then you should be able to do something like this:

```
public class SearchFieldView : UIView, IMvxBindable
{
    public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext { get; set; }

    public SearchFieldView()
    {
         this.CreateBindingContext();
    }

    public UITextField SearchResult { get { return _searchResult; } }
    private UITextField _searchResult;

    public UITableView FoundFilters { get { return _foundFilters; } }
    private UITableView _foundFilters;

    [MvxSetToNullAfterBinding]
    public object DataContext
    {
        get { return BindingContext.DataContext; }
        set { BindingContext.DataContext = value; }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            BindingContext.ClearAllBindings();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And then it should just "work."  For inspiration checkout things like [MvxView](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/e9802dfb45f0d52da3fb056b020032963142b9c3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxView.cs) or [MvxTableViewCell](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/e9802dfb45f0d52da3fb056b020032963142b9c3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxTableViewCell.cs).

---

Alternatively you may be able to do your own MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding like how MvvmCross is handling the UISegmentedControlBindings by implementing something like [MvxUISegmentedControlSelectedSegmentTargetBinding](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/de9081360a952cfa8e8311cd2ed11b464bf4a8ed/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Target/MvxUISegmentedControlSelectedSegmentTargetBinding.cs).

Comment: thanks for answer but solution was little bit easier